# Getting out of the inner loop and contnuing with the outer loop

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i have a while loop which is fetching data from csv.Inside while loop there is a condition(if condition) if the condition is true foreach loop will get executed where we want to insert one row at a time into the database.This should continue for every row of the csv. if I have 10 rows in csv,it should insert all 10 rows in the database.But mycode is inserting the first row 10 times.

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['upcsv']['tmp_name'], "r");
$count = count(file($_FILES['upcsv']['tmp_name']));
fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
   $clt = mysql_query("select MCLNTLKNOFLG,MCLNTDKTRNGFRM,MCLNTDKTRNGTO from mclientmst where MCLNTCD ='".$data[1]."'");
   if(mysql_num_rows($clt)>0)
   {    
      $clts = mysql_fetch_array($clt);
      if($clts['MCLNTLKNOFLG']==1)
      {
         $i=1 ;
         foreach(range ($clts['MCLNTDKTRNGFRM'], $clts['MCLNTDKTRNGTO']) as $num)
         {
           $dkt = mysql_query("select XCMPCD from  xdockethdr where XDKTNO ='$num'");
           $ndkt = mysql_query("select XCMPCD from  xtempdockethdr where XDKTNO ='$num'");
           if(mysql_num_rows($dkt)==0 && mysql_num_rows($ndkt)==0)
           {
              $date = explode('/',$data[3]);
              $dt = $date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[0];
              $dktid = mysql_query("select MAX(XDKTID) as maxid from xtempdockethdr");
              $maxid = mysql_fetch_array($dktid);
              $max = $maxid['maxid'] +1;
              $query = mysql_query("insert into xtempdockethdr (XCMPCD,XCLNTCD,XDKTNO,XCNSGCD,XDKTPUDATE,XDKTPUTIME,XDKTNOPKGS,XDKTMODLV,XDKTHTOCONCD,XDKTDCTVAL,XDKTDIMWT,XDKTACTWT,XUNIQUEID,XDKTID) VALUES ('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$num."','".$data[2]."','".$dt."','".$data[4]."','".$data[5]."','".$data[6]."','".$data[7]."','".$data[8]."','".$data[9]."','".$data[10]."','".$data[11]."','".$max."')");   
              $i++; 
           }
         }
      }
   }    
}
fclose($handle);
header('Location:upload_docketentry.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to set a `break;` after your code. 
   It will close first loop (foreach) and goes down.
2. Add `continue 2;` after sql inserts.
   this will end this loop and goes to the begining of while loop and continue work.

   ```
   $handle = fopen($_FILES['upcsv']['tmp_name'], "r");
   $count = count(file($_FILES['upcsv']['tmp_name']));
   fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) // **#1 point**
   {
      $clt = mysql_query("select MCLNTLKNOFLG,MCLNTDKTRNGFRM,MCLNTDKTRNGTO from mclientmst where MCLNTCD ='".$data[1]."'");
      if(mysql_num_rows($clt)>0)
      {    
         $clts = mysql_fetch_array($clt);
         if($clts['MCLNTLKNOFLG']==1)
         {
            $i=1 ;
            foreach(range ($clts['MCLNTDKTRNGFRM'], $clts['MCLNTDKTRNGTO']) as $num)
            {
              $dkt = mysql_query("select XCMPCD from  xdockethdr where XDKTNO ='$num'");
              $ndkt = mysql_query("select XCMPCD from  xtempdockethdr where XDKTNO ='$num'");
              if(mysql_num_rows($dkt)==0 && mysql_num_rows($ndkt)==0)
              {
                 $date = explode('/',$data[3]);
                 $dt = $date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[0];
                 $dktid = mysql_query("select MAX(XDKTID) as maxid from xtempdockethdr");
                 $maxid = mysql_fetch_array($dktid);
                 $max = $maxid['maxid'] +1;
                 $query = mysql_query("insert into xtempdockethdr (XCMPCD,XCLNTCD,XDKTNO,XCNSGCD,XDKTPUDATE,XDKTPUTIME,XDKTNOPKGS,XDKTMODLV,XDKTHTOCONCD,XDKTDCTVAL,XDKTDIMWT,XDKTACTWT,XUNIQUEID,XDKTID) VALUES ('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$num."','".$data[2]."','".$dt."','".$data[4]."','".$data[5]."','".$data[6]."','".$data[7]."','".$data[8]."','".$data[9]."','".$data[10]."','".$data[11]."','".$max."')");   
                 $i++; 
                 // continue 2; // Goes to #1
                 // break; // Goes to #2
              }
            } // #2 point
            var_dump(__LINE__); // This will executed if you place break operator
         }
      }    
   }
   fclose($handle);
   header('Location:upload_docketentry.php');
   ```